# Graphing user sessions vs transactions

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to graph user sessions (or page views) against transactions on our website via Google Analytics.

I can easily get transactions OR sessions to show up, but not both.

In the picture below I'm in the Ecommerce Overview section. I expect "sessions" to be available in the "vs. Select a metric" text below, but it's not there.

[image]

My goal is to find the relationship (if any) of site sessions (or page views, or unique visitors) against transactions. I'm thinking there should be a strong correlation between the two.

How do I graph both Transactions and Sessions on the same graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [export the data](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1038573?hl=en) from your two metrics in CSV format.   Then you can load them into a speadsheet and graph them yourself there.

There are only a few ways to get multiple lines on the same graph in Google Analytics that I know of and none of them will do exactly what you want.

#### Compare segments

This is probably the closest to what you want, but it isn't exact.   You could create a segment that is "Sessions with a transaction".   Then you could apply that segment and the "All sessions" segment to your Sessions graph.  That would give you a sense of what percentage of sessions had transactions.  On days where you got more sessions, you could see if more of sessions also had transactions.   It would diverge from what you want if many of your visitors have multiple transactions in a session.

#### Compare time periods

You can use the "compare" checkbox in the date selector to see the same metric for two time periods

#### Motion charts

You can use the motion charts feature to see a line for each sub-metric on the graph.   This doesn't allow you to graph and correlate metrics that are not in the same hierarchy though.